# Nhibernate Formula Attribute not mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, attributes

I have a basic nHibernate that I am trying to use a formula mapping attribute on:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsValueApprovalRequired] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @ValueApprovalID BigInt
)
RETURNS Bit
AS
BEGIN
    return CAST(1 as bit)
END
```

my class definition is pretty simple, and I am trying to map the formula to the class like so:

```
[Class(Table="MyTable")]    
public class MyClass
{
    private long _id;
    /// <summary>
    /// A unique identifier for the object
    /// </summary>
    [Id(0, Name = "ID", Column = "ValueApproval_ID")]
    [Generator(1, Class = "identity")]
    public override long ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }
    }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Formula(Content = "(SELECT dbo.IsValueApprovalRequired(ID))")]
    private bool _isValueApprovalRequired;
    /// <summary>
    /// returns if this approval is considered required.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsValueApprovalRequired
    {
        get { return _isValueApprovalRequired; }
    }
}
```

The class is getting loaded, but the variable that is mapped to the formula is not getting populated.

Does anyone know why this is not working? I watch the sql request, and the scalar is not in the given select statement.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Does that work on a private modifier?  Can you try it on the public virtual property?

Comment: That is the strange thing, I have a bunch of private member variables that my mappings can assign fine, but it seems like it is just ignoring this formula attribute. I attached the nhibernate profiler, and nhibernate is not including the select in the sql either.

Answer (score 0):

we had this problem too.

You need to modify your code and add a PropertyAttribute:

```
[Property, Formula(Content = "(SELECT dbo.IsValueApprovalRequired(ID))")]
```